# Can I select specific columns with Hibernate "createCriteria()"?

Tags: java, hibernate, createcriteria

I used `createCriteria()` and `setFetchMode()` methods to join and select. I don't need all columns so I want to select specific columns to improve performance, but I can't find how to do it. Maybe should I use HQL instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to set [Projection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) on specific properties.

Example:

```
 criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.property("cat.name"), "catName" )
    .add( Projections.property("kit.name"), "kitName" )
 );
```

Comment: Do you have any example if joined multiple tables and if we need to return only some columns from each table